# Check if filename (string) starts with a number or symbol

Tags: powershell

I have a large collection of files (.mp3's) that I'm trying to find duplicates of.

The problem I have now is that the filenames can look like below:

```
Singer - Song
_1_Singer_-_Song_
001-Singer-Song
```

What I need to do is:

```
If the name starts with a number (123456789) or a symbol (?=/&%¤#"!_.-).
Then delete all numbers/symbols until there is an alphabetic character.
```

The filenames above should then (hopefully) look like this:

```
Singer - Song
Singer_-_Song_
Singer-Song
```

This is what I have so far but I only need to replace the first characters of the name. They can vary from 0-10 characters so I somehow need to check how many characters that needs to be replaced in every file.

```
$allNames = (Get-ChildItem D:\test)
Foreach ($name in $allNames)
{
    $name | Rename-Item -NewName {$name.Name -replace "_"," "}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Generally, you need to show some code so that readers can see that you made an attempt.  This one is pretty easy, so perhaps someone will help you anyway...

Comment: Google "powershell remove leading non alpha characters".  That should be enough of a push in the right direction.

Comment: There are a number of sites and test sites to play with REGEX.  You can very easily set up a search that will do what you want

Comment: Sorry guys for a bad question (my first one in the Q&A). I have updated the question. When I Googled around I only found how to replace leading characters if you know how many they are or what exactly they are. @TonyHinkle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regex

This is easier with a little regular expression. Replace all leading characters that are not letters

```
$name | Rename-Item -NewName {$name.Name -replace "^[^a-z]*"}
```

- `^` assert position at start of a line
- `[^a-z]*` match a single character not present in the list below

  Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

  `a-z` a single character in the range between a and z. `-replace` is not case-sensitive by default.

---

### String methods

Regex is not the only answer for this though. It appears you have a defined list of characters that should not exist at the start. The string method `.TrimStart()` would work as well.

```
$name | Rename-Item -NewName {($name.Name).TrimStart("0123456789?=/&%¤#`"!_.-")}
```

I added the 0 so it would fit your test cases.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question.

Comment: The first example worked fine in my test-directory but when I did it "live" it did not work. The script went through without errors but it did not change anything. However, I then tried your TrimStart on my real directory and that worked like a charm (I needed to add some characters though). Thanks again.

Comment: Pretty sure a bunch of those are not legal in file names anyway so they shouldn't even show up. Not sure why the regex didn't work in live (I only tested on strings.). Glad something works either way.